# Xcode 15 with FireBase SDK Unable to process Info.plist during build process

Tags: xcode15

After upgrade the latest Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d), Can't build success with below error:

```
Unable to process Info.plist during build process
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally, I solved this error by move the position of Runscript to the end.
[image]

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731059

Comment: Don't forget to set NO for `User Script Sandboxing` in your target Build settings.

Comment: Great solution. Works for me.
Where you can find **Run Script**
`Targets -> Build Phase -> Run Script` (drag Run Script to the bottom)

Comment: Saved my day. Only in my case, I dragged "Run Script" to the second last, and "Firebase Crashlytics Script" to the last.

Comment: its not working for mee